# Black spots on areca palm stem

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, palm

I have black spots all over the stems of my Areca palm. I did have fungus in the soil, but I changed the soil and now everything seems good there. Can this come from the fungus that I had? [image]

Answer (score 2):

The seller of my areca palm says it is black fungus and it won't kill the areca palm. However, it is spreading all over the stems. Here is photo. I cleaned some off already with damp cotton ball.[image: yellowing stems with black fungus spots on areca palm.]

Answer (score 1):

These are a fungus/virus/bacteria living inside the plant and are very common with areca palms.  They are not a problem and no action is required.  More details can be found in my answer [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/16135/499)