# What are these brown dot on my palm stems

Tags: indoors, palm

Hi my palm has developed these small brown spots on the stem any ideas what it is?

The edges of the fronds are also browning /turning yellow

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an Areca Palm (Dypsis lutescens). If so, those dots are common (nearly universal) and are no cause for concern. Check out [kevinsky's answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/16135/499) to a similar question for more information.